# Spring BasicAuthenticationFilter and UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter on different server than actual application

Tags: java, spring, jwt, load-balancing

I am currently developing a REST-application which needs to be very scalable. From what I have learned about load balancing, one should split up the actual application into independent parts. So far I've separated creating accounts and the login from the actual application. I followed [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) tutorial to implement JWT. Is that best practice or can this solution be improved?

However, I have my actual REST-application as a separate project. Obviously, these two applications need to work together. How can I accomplish that? Is there a way to store the Token & access it in the second application?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow microservices architecture. [This](https://medium.com/@arjunac009/spring-boot-microservice-with-centralized-authentication-zuul-eureka-jwt-5719e05fde29) example has end to end description of what you wanted.

Since, what you needed to implement is of very large scope, you can ask us in case youu have any issue with the MicroServices Architecture.

Cool!

Comment: When I follow this tutorial, I get the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start`

Comment: I just launched the Java code provided in the linked GitHub repos but I always get the same error as above. Is there anything I have to watch?